# How to add category to my polls app?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

My models.py is

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Is Published')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Question_Image", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

And, I have to add a class "category" so that each of my question could select one of four categories: world, technology, screen and sports.. For example, my one category html i have is screen.html and i need to display only questions based on category 'screen'. Here's my screen.html.

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}
{% block main_content %}
{% if latest_questions %}
<body>
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
        {% for question in latest_questions %}
        <li style="float:center">
            <div id="tabs"><a id="tabsword" href={% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}>
                <img id="tabsimage" align="middle" src='{{question.image.url}}'/>
                <p style=" font-size: 25px; font-family: Verdana; color: whitesmoke; text-align: center"><b>{{question.question_text}}</b></p>
            </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p> You have no questions. Please add some.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Help me modify the codes in a way so that i could add class category, assign each question out of four category and display only questions based on category "screen" on the above html.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create another model for categories, one simple way to do this would be to do the following (from the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#field-options) on field options):

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    SHIRT_SIZES = (
        ('S', 'Small'),
        ('M', 'Medium'),
        ('L', 'Large'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    shirt_size = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SHIRT_SIZES)
```

Just replace the names of shirt sizes with the model field and choices that you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are no of ways to do so.
for example define choices in your model

```
class Question(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_SIZES = (
        ('W', 'WORlD'),
        ('T', 'TECHNOLOGY'),
        ('S', 'SCREEN'),
    )
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Is Published')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Question_Image", blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CATEGORY_SIZES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

In your views.py

```
def your_view(request):
    questions = Question.objects.filter(category='S')
    context = {'questions': questions}
    return render(request, your_template ,context)
```

Other way: If you think seperate model will be better choice for you

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Is Published')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Question_Image", blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

In views.py

```
def your_view(request):
    category = Category.objects.get(name='Screen')
    questions = category.question_set.all()
    context = {'questions': questions}
    return render(request, your_template,context)
```